# Install Drupal with SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: php, sql-server-2008, drupal-6, sql-server-2008-r2

Is it possible in any ways to connect Drupal 6.x to SQL Server 2008 R2? I am really struggling to find a way out.

please let me know. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, by default, Microsoft SQL Server is not within the Drupal 6 system requirements.

Additionally, if you need that database server, it's highly suggested to use Drupal 7 instead which has PDO support and PDO supports (somehow) Microsoft SQL Server.